# Convert Python List to Column in CSV

Tags: python

I have a list of values (v1, v2, v3) and I want to write these to a column called VALUES in a csv.  I'm using csvreader and csvwriter to get as far as I have.  I've only figured out how to write them to rows using csvwriter.writerow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have tried:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
thecsv = csv.writer(open("your.csv", 'wb'))
thecsv.writerow(values)
```

Perhaps you should try:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
thecsv = csv.writer(open("your.csv", 'wb'))
for value in values:
    thecsv.writerow(value)
```

Comment: I tried that.  My values have multiple characters (v1, v2, v3) and when I use the method you suggest, row 1 column 1 gets "v", row 1 column 2 gets "1", row 2 column 1 gets "v", row 2 column 2 gets "2" etc.

Comment: Try changing `thecsv.writerow(value)` to `thecsv.writerow([value])`.