# Flatten list of list into one column [Python]

Tags: python

I have data like this:

```
[[var, list], [x1, [x,y,z]], [x2, [a,b,c]]]
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
[[var, list], [x1, x],[x1,y],[x1,z], [x2, a],[x2,b],[x2,c]]
```

But I don't know how.

Comment: Are you using a library?

Comment: I'm using the csv library

Comment: Hello! A couple of suggestions for your question so that it will meet community guidelines: 1) Always show what you have attempted. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but if you have attempted the task at hand and are stuck on a specific part or don't understand a particular command, say so. Then the community will be happy to help. 2) Make sure you're actually asking a question. This "question" has no question mark in it, just a vague statement of what you want to do. 3) Don't include tags in titles; titles are for titles, tags are for tags, so they go in different places.

Comment: maybe something like [Convert Python List to Column in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902944/convert-python-list-to-column-in-csv)?

Comment: @NBC In addition to DavyM's suggestions, you need to clarify what you are doing.  The data that you show simply does not look like python data.  In all likelihood, you are using some additional package (other than csv) or some interface that makes the data look like what you show.  You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more details.

Comment: I was trying to visually show how the data is structured, but I have edited to give an accurate python representation

Comment: Thanks Davy - edited the post. In terms of what I have tried, not much. I could iteratively run through all entries and create a new list, but that seems inefficient. Wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: This looks like pandas. Is it?

Comment: not pandas, not sure what that is

Comment: @NBC To remove ambiguity, show your actual python commands and their actual output.  Copy-and-paste from the python terminal without any additional "visual" formatting on your part.

Comment: ok done. is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with my interpretation of your starting list:

```
>>> z = [['var', ['list']], ['x1', ['x','y','z']], ['x2', ['a','b','c']]]
```

To rearrange it maybe as you want:

```
>>> [ [[x, y] for y in lst] for x, lst in z]
[[['var', 'list']], [['x1', 'x'], ['x1', 'y'], ['x1', 'z']], [['x2', 'a'], ['x2', 'b'], ['x2', 'c']]]
```

Or, rearranging further:

```
>>> a = []
>>> for x in [ [[x, y] for y in lst] for x, lst in z]:
...     a += x
... 
>>> a
[['var', 'list'], ['x1', 'x'], ['x1', 'y'], ['x1', 'z'], ['x2', 'a'], ['x2', 'b'], ['x2', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an optimal solution, but it uses very basic python commands so that you'll be able to keep track of what's going on.

```
data = [['var', 'list'], ['x1', ['x','y','z']], ['x2', ['a','b','c']]]
final = []
for pair in data:
    if pair == ['var', 'list'] :
        final.append(pair)
    else:
        for entry in pair[1]:
            final.append([pair[0], entry])
print(final)
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured I can do it this way but was hoping for something more elegant. Much appreciated!